# How can a build or test a smaller nixos container config independent of my host's Nixos config?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm trying to configure a container within nixos `containers` for example:

```
  containers.abc123 = {
    config = { config, pkgs, ... }:
    {
      systemd.services = {
        finder-email-requests = {
          description = "";
          enable = true;
          environment = {
              TESTING = "abcxyz";
          };
          serviceConfig = {
            Type      = "simple";

            ExecStart = "bash -c \"echo '$TESTING hello' >> /tmp/abcxyz\"";
            Restart   = "always";
            RestartSec   = 30;
          };
          wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
        };
      };
    };
  };
```

However needing to test/compile this means running `nixos-rebuild test` which can take 10+ seconds on my machine (or 7s on a newly installed VM I just tried).

**Is there some way I can more quickly test this container config independent from my entire host's Nixos config?** For example building just the container config itself rather than the entire instance of this nixos config?

---

I've found that the `nixos-rebuild` command is a small shell script for example at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/216f0e6ee4a65219f37caed95afda1a2c66188dc/nixos/modules/installer/tools/nixos-rebuild.sh

However after reading through it, I don't quite understand whats going on in terms of the relationship between this 'containers' unit and the general 'nixos config'.

Comment: `nixos-rebuild` is a _very_ generic wrapper around the activation script. It has to be compatible with other NixOS releases. Containers are implemented [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/virtualisation/nixos-containers.nix) if you're interested in the implementation of it.

Comment: @Chris I've been googling around about NixOS containers and ran into https://github.com/erikarvstedt/extra-container - it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NixOS Containers don't have a testing facility of their own (as of Nov 2020). They behave like normal NixOS systems for most intents and purposes. If you want to test your container, a normal NixOS test should be adequate.

Writing NixOS tests is [documented](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-nixos-tests) in the NixOS manual. You can use the `pkgs.nixosTest` function to write your own tests outside of the Nixpkgs repo.

You could test either an approximation of the host system with your container, or just the container configuration as if it was the "top-level" NixOS system. I'd go with the latter, unless you need to test multiple containers in conjunction, or if you need to test interactions between host and container.

However to test the container definition building correctly, we can use `pkg.nixos`. For example, a nix expression for your container (that can be be built with the usual `nix-build` method):

```
{ a = let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in (pkgs.nixos
{
  fileSystems."/".device = "x";
  boot.loader.grub.enable = false;

  systemd.services = {
          finder-email-requests-2 = {
            description = "";
            enable = true;
            environment = {
                TESTING = "abcxyz";
            };
            serviceConfig = {
              Type      = "simple";

              ExecStart = "bash -c \"echo '$TESTING hello' >> /tmp/abcxyz\"";
              Restart   = "always";
              RestartSec   = 30;
            };
            wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
          };
        };
}).toplevel; 
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I'd imagine this still wouldn't be faster than using my host's nixos config directly though? It's the 10s +\- wait I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: A minimal NixOS configuration takes ~3s to evaluate. Evaluating more of those in the same process adds a similar amount. It's reasonable to assume that's the same for containers. Testing your container's config as "host" in `nixosTest` should therefore save ~3s. Your numbers may vary. See for yourself: `time nix-instantiate --expr '{ a = let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; in (pkgs.nixos { fileSystems."/".device = "x"; boot.loader.grub.enable = false; }).toplevel; }'`. You can also play with reusing `pkgs` for ~0.5s impact. See also the `nixpkgs.pkgs` option.

Comment: I should note that `nixosTest` is not like `nixos-rebuild test`; it doesn't give you a VM to interact with, but lets you run a test script.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I appreciate the addition of your example, but it's calling the `nixos` function instead of `nixosTest`. This is more like calling `nixos-rebuild build`, but able to be incorporated in another expression and built with the `nix-build command`.

Comment: Ah sorry copied that from the comment - but it seems to do exactly what I had in mind in my question (where my intention of 'test' was - test that it successfully 'builds'). I'll try edit the the answer once again to be more clear, feel free to rollback otherwise (and I can put as separate answer).